# search for records that belongs to current user Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I want to search for records that belongs to the current user only

Here is my Controller code :

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $branches = Branch::all();
        if(Auth::user()->shortsign == '--')
        {

            $deposits = Deposit::query()
                ->where([['client', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%"]])
                ->orWhere([['mobile', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%"]])
                ->orWhere([['amount', '=', "{$request->search}"]])
                ->orWhere([['id', '=', "{$request->search}"]])
                ->latest()->paginate(5);
            return view('dashboard.deposits.index', array('deposits' => $deposits,
                'branches' => $branches ,'users' => $users));
        }
        else
        {

            $deposits = Deposit::where([['userSign',Auth::user()->shortsign]],function ($q) use ($request){
                return  $q->when($request->search,function ($query) use ($request) {
                    return $query->where([['client', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%"]])
                        ->orWhere([['mobile', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%"]])
                        ->orWhere([['amount', '=', "{$request->search}"]])
                        ->orWhere([['id', '=', "{$request->search}"]]);
                });

            })->latest()->paginate(5);
            return view('dashboard.deposits.index', array('deposits' => $deposits,
                'branches' => $branches ,'users' => $users));

        }

    }
```

when i am login as normal user and search nothing happens it bring all current user rows without filter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can just do like this

```
if(auth()->user()->shortsign == '--') {
    $deposits = Deposit::where('client', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
                ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
                ->orWhere('amount', '=', "$request->search%")
                ->orWhere('id', '=', "$request->search%")
                ->latest()->paginate(5);
}
else {
    $deposits = Deposit::where('userSign',Auth::user()->shortsign)->latest()- 
                >paginate(5);
}
```

and in your view file you can foreach and use properties like

```
foreach($deposites as $d) {
         {{ $d->id }} {{ $d->amount }}
 }
```

It will search like if user short sign is -- it will search for all users and get you the ouput but if auth()->user()->shortsign is not -- 
It will get the result of current logged in user only

Let me know if you have wanted this

Comment: thanks but still same result when i press search button it brings all current user records but i cannot filter or search between these rows